# Waveform Generator Ripple on Pos. Sine Crest

Tags: test-equipment

Acquired a used GW Instek 8020H.  During cursory testing, it was found to have excessive ripple at the positive crest, along with very minimal ripple at the negative crest.  This ripple appears also on the Triangle waveform, but the Square waveform is perfect.  A 50 ohm attenuator is installed at the scope and is connected with a coax cable. This issue is identical on both channels of the scope and there's no other reason to suspect the scope. I noticed it with the wave form compressed. In the attached image it is rather expanded.
I am wondering what might be the possible cause, typically.

[image]

Comment: My guess is that whatever is generating the sine and triangle waves, there could be a faulty component that is causing and overshoot ripple, potentially capturing noise somewhere.

Comment: OK, I found a post that addresses this problem (via Google).  The output level was increased and the ripple practically disappeared.  Apparently, this has to do with the nature of the generating circuit.  Too bad for that limitation; I usually use it for audio inputs of either 0.1 or 1V RMS to test amplifiers for levels and response, so it doesn't even matter. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/449431/waveforms-from-a-function-generator-what-is-good-enough